# Embedding google maps on a site

Tags: html, google-maps

I created a custom map on Google maps so I could show the area that a camera is looking out on using the polygons. However on my site the map starts a long way from the marker.

Here is my html:

```
<td style="width:380px; text-align:right;" valign="top">
<div style="padding:1px;">                                                
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zVK_XsZ9U8JQ.k7gXFo9LSEvk"></iframe><br /><small>
<a href="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zVK_XsZ9U8JQ.k7gXFo9LSEvk" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a>
</small>
</div>
</td>
```

Is there something I can add to the HTML to make it start where the marker is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chech this [Embedding Maps into a Website](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/websitemaps.html)

Comment: I did that before but the map doesn't start near the marker I put into the map, I'm thinking I should probably use google maps apis

Comment: It requires the use of the google maps api. The custom markers are just images that can be used. The example there is very elegant by moving to a selected marker based on click.

for a full overview of the google maps api goto: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html